# gem install rails - undefined method hexdigest for OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install rails in a fresh installation of OS X (Mavericks) and this command

`gem install rails`

gives

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
   undefined method `hexdigest' for #<OpenSSL::Digest:0...>
```

I've installed rvm using:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

and homebrew using:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Xcode & its Command Line Tools are already installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried: `rvm use ruby --install` before `gem install rails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue on my Mac after a migration from Mac OS X 10.8 to OS 10.9 Mavericks.

Ruby 2 was working perfectly on OS 10.8 (installed with RVM). But after the migration, ruby 2 and rails 3.2 were starting to behave strangely.

So I've followed the step by step instructions from http://www.computersnyou.com/2673/2013/10/install-ruby-rails-macos-x-mavericks-10-9-mysql-step-step/

Lesson 1 : Do not try to re-install. Uninstall and install

```
rvm uninstall ruby-2.0.0-p247
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Then I've got an issue with pristine :

```
command(4): __rvm_with ruby-2.0.0-p247 /Users/fred/.rvm/scripts/gemsets pristine
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2 bigdecimal-1.2.0 binding_of_caller-0.7.2 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `hexdigest' for #<OpenSSL::Digest:0x000001024ffda0>
```

Retried with :

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247 --verify-downloads 2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
```

and it succeeds until I need to compile libv8.

I've downloaded the following gem binary https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7919548/gems/libv8/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-13.gem coming

```
gem install ~/Downloads/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-13.gem
gem install bundler --pre
```

And my ruby is working well as before !
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall ruby pointing to the openssl dir:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
```